# Mojolicious source IP and user agent

Tags: perl, mojolicious

I have the following Mojolicious app which serving files from specific folder

```
use Mojolicious::Lite;
use Mojo::Log;

my $app = app;
my $static = $app->static;
push @{$static->paths} => 'c:\test';

$app->start
```

when I run:

```
perl mojo_server.pl daemon -m development
```

I get this:

```
[2021-05-18 19:46:39.22370] [29388] [info] Listening at "http://*:3000"
Server available at http://127.0.0.1:3000
```

and when I access a file from the web browser I am able to access the file, but there are no information on the STDERR after "Server available at [http://127.0.0.1:3000"](http://127.0.0.1:3000%22)
like what is the source address and the page requested and the user agent. How can I turn mojolicious to show those info on debug mode, if this possible?

Comment: You might be interested in https://metacpan.org/pod/App::HTTPThis.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion but i am restricted to use Mojolicious ,as this prototype where on the future i am going to change the logic and not accessing the files from the folder.

Comment: Typically you look for the request info in an access log, but you have to make your application write that information to such a file.

Comment: @briandfoy I agree with you in this ,usually web servers has a common format like NCSA https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Log_Format  ,i thought maybe there are a possiblity to enable such format with Mojolicious using some debugging flag to STDERR to see those info , but from the answer below i noticed the the developer should deal with the log in every case and no default format.

Comment: @dave I thought your question was specifically about serving static files. Take a Look at [AccessLog](https://metacpan.org/pod/Mojolicious::Plugin::AccessLog) for a more general solution. (updated answer)

Comment: Thanks clamp for your effort and helpful answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `after_static` from *HOOKS* in [Mojolicious](https://docs.mojolicious.org/Mojolicious):

```
use Mojolicious::Lite -signatures;
use Mojo::Log;

my $log = Mojo::Log->new;

hook after_static => sub ($c){
    $log->debug('original_remote_address : ' => $c->tx->original_remote_address);
    $log->debug('user_agent : ' => $c->tx->req->content->headers->user_agent );
    $log->debug('url : ' => $c->tx->req->url->to_abs);
};
app->start;
```

The `after_static` event is triggered when a static response has been generated.

Update: If you need a more general solution which is not specifically targeted at serving static files, take a look at the [AccessLog](https://metacpan.org/pod/Mojolicious::Plugin::AccessLog) plugin.

```
use Mojolicious::Lite -signatures;
use Mojo::Log;
use Mojolicious::Plugin::AccessLog;

my $log = Mojo::Log->new;
plugin 'AccessLog';
app->start;
```